# Binding a calculated field in Blazor

Tags: blazor-server-side

I have a form that allows me to create an entity. There are a few decimal model properties bound and working. A new requirement came where I have to show totals as the decimal field value are changed.

So, the user will change the four numeric inputs to any value and I need the QTotal to update on the fly. Here is what I did and it doesn't work as intended. The QTotal only picks up the value of Q1:

Page:

```
    <DxFormLayoutGroup Caption="Additional Budget Info (Optional)" ColSpanMd="12">
        @*Inputs ffor Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4*@
        <DxFormLayoutItem Caption="Q Total:" ColSpanMd="2">
            <Template >
                <DxSpinEdit Id="approvedTotals" @bind-Value="@Model.QTotal" DisplayFormat="N2" ReadOnly="true"/>
            </Template >
        </DxFormLayoutItem >
    </DxFormLayoutGroup>
```

Code behind:

```
public class BudgetReleaseRequestViewModel
{

    [Display(Name = "Approved Q1")]
    public decimal? ApprovedQ1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Approved Q2")]
    public decimal? ApprovedQ2 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Approved Q3")]
    public decimal? ApprovedQ3 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Approved Q4")]
    public decimal? ApprovedQ4 { get; set; }

    public decimal? QTotal
    {
        get => ApprovedQ1 ?? 0 + ApprovedQ2 ?? 0 + ApprovedQ3 ?? 0 + ApprovedQ4 ?? 0;
        set => QTotal = value;
    }

    public decimal? QDelta => ApprovedAnnualBudget ?? 0 - QTotal;

}
```

Obviously, it is not going to be this simple as there needs to be some kind of event binding to update the value of QTotal for the UI as per Blazor. Would like some help here.

Comment: It would be better if you'd reduce your question code to the salient issue.  I'm not much inclined to weed through these walls of text to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973, I removed all non-essential bricks from the wall. Also highlighted what I'm trying to solve. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a job for ReactiveUI? https://www.reactiveui.net/blog/2020/07/article-blazor-compelling-example
I'm new to Blazor, coming in form the worlds of React, Svelte and KnockoutJS. I'm suprised at the lack of Reactivity based examples to be honest, especially given Steve Sanderson's involvement.